# Classify mongoose schema arrays by date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is the Schema:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({

  user: String,
  messages: [{ 

              title: String,
              author: String,
              message: String,
              date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },

           }],

});
```

I'm trying to show all the users' message in a single page ordered by date. I know how for example show all the messages of a specific user, but if I have multiple users, I don't know how to classificate their message by date using mongoose. Is there any way to do this...?

Thank's advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the aggregation framework and `$unwind` the `messages` array so that you can `$sort` them all by `date`:

```
Users.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$messages'},
    {$sort: {'messages.date': 1}}
], function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: If I want to do that, but selecting some specific users, should I change some thing?

Comment: @MrMangado Add a [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_match) operator to the pipeline to filter the docs.

Comment: Is possible to use the `$match` operator with an array?

Comment: @MrMangado You'd include it after the `$unwind` so that `messages` is no longer an array when it's applied.

Comment: But, I meant that if I could search the messages of specific users, using `$match`, with an array that has the `_id`s of the users.

Comment: @MrMangado Sure, you'd use `$match` with an [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/#_S_in) operator for that.

Comment: It works perfectly :D But, instead to receive a whole user schema with the `messages`' schema  within it, is posible to get only the `messages`' schema?